# Loading a string ot a JTable column

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have a problem filling my JTable with values I have stored in a string.

The string has the form:

```
String factor = {"UMIN2\nT_UMIN2\nUMIN1\nT_UMIN1\nUMAX1\nT_UMAX1\nUMAX2\nT_UMAX2"};
```

and the code for the Jtable looks like:

```
    int len = factor.split("[\n\r]").length;
    final String[] columnNames = {"Factor", "Tol, min", "Exp, min", "Exp, max", "Tol, max", "Test 1", "Test 2", "Test 3", "Test 4", "Test 5", "Test 6", "Test 7", "Test 8", "Test 9", "Test 10"};
    final Object[][] data = {{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},        };
    model = new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames);
    model.setRowCount(len);
    table = new JTable(data, columnNames);
    table.setModel(model);

    for(int x = 0; x < len; x++) table.setValueAt(factor,x,0);

    JTableHeader header = table.getTableHeader();
    header.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.BOLD, 13));
    header.setBackground(Color.black);
    header.setForeground(Color.white);

    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
    scrollPane.setSize(988, 618);
    scrollPane.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.BOLD, 13));
    scrollPane.setLocation(10, 60);
    getContentPane().add(scrollPane);
```

What I am getting looks like:

```
[   **factor**   ]
[ UMIN2T_... ]
[ UMIN2T_... ]
[ UMIN2T_... ]
[ UMIN2T_... ]
[ UMIN2T_... ]
[ UMIN2T_... ]
[ UMIN2T_... ]
[ UMIN2T_... ]
```

However what I am looking for is that every newline entry gets its own box so that i looks like:

```
[ **factor** ]
[ UMIN2  ]
[ T_UMIN2]
[ UMIN1  ]
[ T_UMIN1]
[ UMAX1  ]
[ T_UMAX1]
[ UMAX2  ]
[ T_UMAX2]
```

Right now I am using the setValueAt function.

I have also tried to alter the height of the box and have all data in only one dox, this Works fine however, I need the individual boxes because I later on have to color them according to other data in the table.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: This would an issue with the `TableCellRenderer`, which, by default, is based off a `JLabel` and the column width.  I'm, also concerned by the use of `setSize` and `setLocation`.  You should be using a proper layout manager as this has the capacity to better handle differences between OS's

Comment: I am using setSize and setLocation because I also need space for other information in my window, such as title and button to back and print.

Comment: I can see a `BorderLayout` with a `JToolBar` and `JPanel` acting as a navigation panel.  Absolute layouts will not help you in the long and will explode in your face the moment that the font changes or the DPI changes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to split factor and set each token to each row.

```
    int row = 0;
    for (StringTokenizer stringTokenizer = new StringTokenizer(factor, "\n"); stringTokenizer.hasMoreTokens();) {
        String token = stringTokenizer.nextToken();
        table.setValueAt(token, row++, 0);
    }
```